# jmeter re-login after request takes long time

Tags: jmeter

The website allows a user to be idle only for 15 mins, after which he gets logged out. Let's say one of the api calls take more than 15 mins and the user's token expires by then. I need to re-login when such a situation occurs.

I have,

```
Thread
- HTTP Cookie manager
- Simple Controller[SC](disabled) -> Login to the site
- Simple Contoller
   -Module Controller -> Call [SC] to login user and get token.
   -Loop 
      -api 1
      -api 2
      -api 3
      -api 4
```

If one of the api calls take more than 15 mins, the token expires and the next call would get an authentication failure error. I want to know if it is possible to have a post processor for each api to check if it is more than 15 mins, if so, it should recall [SC] controller to re-login.

Comment: the approach to add assertion/checker/postporcessor to every API seems odd. is it expected that an API can take 15 minutes to get the response? You can use BeanShell postprocessor and can access response time of each API call using `getTime()` of SampleResult object.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it as follows:

1. Initially setting a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), i.e. `authorised` with the value of `false`
2. Make your Login Controller a part of the loop.
3. Put your Login controller under [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and use `!${authorised}` as the If Controller's "Condition". So Login controller will only be executed if `authorised` variable is `false`
4. If the login is successful you can change `authorised` variable value to `true` using i.e. [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) and code like:

   ```
   if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").equals("true")) {
       vars.put("authorised", "true");
   }
   ```
5. In order to change `authorised` variable back to false if API request takes longer than 15 minutes you can use the same Beanshell PostProcessor and the code like:

   ```
   if (prev.getTime() > 900000) {
       vars.put("authorised", "false");
   }
   ```

   where `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance which holds the parent sampler result data.

Comment: Shouldnt the Login Controller be part of a separate thread and run in a loop. Then it would set the Boolean as required. And the other thread would have the api calls and a post processor would unset the Boolean when >15 mins. How would I make the loop to stop when all my api calls end?